# How to let several phone numbers in one string to be clickable using autolink:phone?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So in my TextView I have several phone numbers separated by slash sign like this for example:

6723098 / 52378529 / (021)854745

Now when I used android:autoLink="phone", only the first number is clickable to automatically dial, how do I set that all three numbers to be clickable and callable?

Thx in advance.

Java

```
public class ShowRestActivity extends Activity {
    String rest_tel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.show_rest);

        TextView restTelLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.restTelLabel);

        restTelLabel.setText("6723098 / 52378529 / (021)854745");
        Linkify.addLinks(restTelLabel, Patterns.PHONE, "tel:");

    }
}
```

xml

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/restTelLabel"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/restNameLabel"
    android:autoLink="phone"/>
```

These are a portion regarding the phone number..

### Solution

Remove `android:autoLink="phone"` from the TextView's attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this...

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textviewid);
textView.setText("6723098 / 52378529 / (021)854745");
Linkify.addLinks(textView, Patterns.PHONE, "tel:");
```

Comment: Thx for your response.. restTelLabel.setText("6723098 / 52378529 / (021)854745");
Linkify.addLinks(restTelLabel, Patterns.PHONE, "tel:"); Still, only the first number is clickable..

Comment: can you explain your answer with text not just code?

Comment: @Charas have you remove the autoLink tag from your xml code. If not then try by removing it.

Comment: Nope, I didn't remove the autoLink tag from my xml code, I have removed it just now and it works like a charm.. Thank you very much sir.. =)

Answer (score 0):

Why not generate 3 (N) TextViews from the input by tokenizing them. Seems harmless to do, numbers may be limited only to the first number found.

Comment: Actually the amount of phone numbers depended on the user input, some user inputted two numbers, or one, could be three, so I don't think creating 3 TextViews will work

Comment: thats according to your example its 3,  but 3 is just N, it doens't have to be three :)

Comment: Or (more complicated) you could build on own regular expression as another alternative to fix the issue, seems that it doesn't scale for what you want.

Comment: Yes maybe, but I am not that good with regex, hoping someone here have a better solution, anyway thanks..

Comment: There is one more thing you can try .. try \n after each number and see if that works.